# Container div doesn't change its width when content is removed using media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Can't figure out how to make proper responsiveness on a page. Already tried everything I knew (explicitly setting width, overflow: hidden). Page is here – http://todaytmrrw.com/

Problem is: div.b-shareContent (main container) is 1024px wide and body height is 1536px no matter what, so when I open page on a phone or in Developer tools Mobile Preview – it looks like a full desktop version with some content hidden. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the code to your problem so we can look at what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is: div.b-shareContent (main container) is 1024px wide

That’s because you are *telling* mobile browsers that the page is that wide, with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

“Normally”, for pages that should just adapt to the device width, one would use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: That is correct. This header to this page was included by php, so I was unable to find 1024 hard-coded there initially. Thank you very much.